# Как выводить объект через Id на js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api

Допустим мы пользуемся [JSON API](http://cheap-shopping-store.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=#_=_) Tumblr ну или любой какой то летны. И когда получаем значение **photo-caption** через jquery то содержания записей получаем в таком формате:

```
<p id="name">Test</p><p id="date">01.01.2021</p><p id="about">Bla Bla Bla</p>
```

И дальше по Json идет еще один пост с таким же результатом:

```
<p id="name">Test 2</p><p id="date">02.01.2021</p><p id="about">Bla Bla Bla</p>
```

Так вот как нам получать значения **name** в отдельную переменную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var s = '<p id="name">Test</p><p id="date">01.01.2021</p><p id="about">Bla Bla Bla</p>';
var $wrapper = $('<div>').html(s);
console.log($wrapper.find('#date').text());
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Можно обойтись без дополнительного элемента, но тогда придётся по-разному искать вложенные и элементы и элементы верхнего уровня:

```js
var s = '<p id="name">Test</p><p id="date">01.01.2021</p><p id="about">Bla <span id="s">Bla</span> Bla</p>';
var $els = $(s);
console.log($els.filter('#date').text());
console.log($els.find('#s').text());
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Mr.Black для дополнительного подчёркивания, что это jquery-объект, и уменьшения каши в голове у тех, кто будет читать код

Comment: Подскажите  а как можно реализовать поиск обьекта, допустим у нас таких много, и мы хотим вывести обьект у которого name = "test"

Comment: @arthru, по селектору атрибута: `[name="test"]`.

Comment: Можно пример кода?

Comment: @arthru, а на сайт jQuery заглянуть?

Comment: Просто не могу понять на примере этого кода, допустим сделаем $('[name = "Test"]'); но а как получить остольне значения этой записи? По типу price, about...

Comment: @arthru, `$(...)` работает в контексте текущего документа. Тебе нужен `find`, как в моём примере.

Comment: Можете именно код дать который удет по именни выводить все остольные значения

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43430/discussion-between-arthru-and-qwertiy).

Answer (score 0):

Из json'а у нас строка, так создадим элемент по ней, а дальше доберёмся селектором до нужного значения по атрибуту

```js
e = document.createElement('p');
e.innerHTML = '<p id="name">Test</p><p id="date">01.01.2021</p><p id="about">Bla Bla Bla</p>';

name = e.querySelector('#name').innerText;
date = e.querySelector('#date').innerText;
about = e.querySelector('#about').innerText;

console.log(name, date, about);
```

```js
json = $('<p>').html(
  '<p id="name">Test</p><p id="date">01.01.2021</p><p id="about">Bla Bla Bla</p>' +
  '<p id="name">Test 2</p><p id="date">02.01.2021</p><p id="about">Bla Bla Bla</p>'
);

name1 = json.find('#name').eq(0).text();
name2 = json.find('#name').eq(1).text();

console.log(name1);
console.log(name2);
```

```html
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
```